# TypeORM joining Relation with condition of data in joined table

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have two tables:

**1. Devices:**

```
    @Entity()
    export class Devices {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!:number;


    @Column({unique:true})
    unique_id!:string
    }
```

**2. Device Details:**

```
    @Entity()
    export class DeviceDetails {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!:number;

    @OneToOne(type => Devices)
    @JoinColumn()
    device!:Devices

    @ManyToOne(type => Customers,customers=>customers.devices,{
        cascade:true
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    customer!:Customers

 
    @ManyToOne(type => Users,users=>users.devices)
    @JoinColumn()
    user!:Users

    @ManyToOne(type => Users,users=>users.devicesmechanic)
    @JoinColumn()
    mechanic!:Users

    @ManyToOne(type => Dealer,dealer=>dealer.devices)
    @JoinColumn()
    dealer!:Dealer

    }
```

What I want to do is to search for `unique_id` which is in the devices table but also join the results of `device_detail` table so that I can include all the details of the device in the search, I have been trying the following, which is working but not returning the result of the device.

```
let device = await getManager().getRepository(DeviceDetails)
            .createQueryBuilder('details')
            .innerJoinAndSelect('devices','devices','devices.unique_id LIKE :unique_id',{unique_id:req.body.unique_id})
            .where("devices.id=details.deviceId")
            .getMany();
```

Comment: your `details` table does not have `deviceId` field.

Comment: The details table contains the field device which is a relation to device table,typeorm translates it to deviceid